# error : add foreign keys in UpgradeSchema

Tags: magento2, error, upgradeschema

I am trying to give foreign keys in Upgrade Schema but it is still not working

```
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<'))
        {
            $setup->getConnection()->modifyColumn(
                $setup->getTable('faq_data'),
                'cat_id',
                ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 'nullable' => false]);

            $setup->getConnection()->addForeignKey(
                $setup->getFkName('faq_data', 'cat_id', $setup->getTable('faq_cat_data'), 'cat_id'),
                $setup->getTable('faq_data'),
                'cat_id',
                $setup->getTable('faq_cat_data'),
                'cat_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: share your error log

Comment: there is a nothing in error log

Comment: @DipakSolanki, you make confuse us.Posted foreign key error bit donot  tell what the  error.Please  explain ther error in brief

Comment: it's not assign foreign key that's my problem there is no such error

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
->addForeignKey(
  $installer->getFkName('<ChildTable>', 'entity_id', '<ParentTable>', 'entity_id'),
  'entity_id',
  $installer->getTable('<ParentTable>'),
  'entity_id',
  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
```

- Make sure both table have same field.
- Set primary key to parent table.
- Change module version in **XML** file
- Run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**